# showint thumbnails issue

Tags: php, image-upload

I am unexperienced in ways of PHP and MySQL, but I am trying to build an image upload website following a tutorial of Kevin Skoglund. Everything was fine up to a point where my images are supposed to show on a page in a html table.

I got everything from my database (image size, type, name, caption), but instead of image thumbnail I get broken link.
Here is relevant html

```
   <tr>
    <td><img src="../<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" width="100" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $photo->filename; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $photo->caption; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $photo->size_as_text(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $photo->type; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Here is php that defines image path

```
protected $upload_dir="images";
public function image_path() {
return $this->upload_dir.DS.$this->filename;
```

}

Site root defined:

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : 
    define('SITE_ROOT', DS.'wamp'.DS.'www'.DS.'projekat');
```

this is folder structure [image]

this is end result [image]

Thanks for taking time to read and help with my problem in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

return $photo->image_path() as

```
 projekat/public/images/filename.jpg
```

and display

```
 <td><img src="/<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>"
```

In html, you can use beginning '/' to indicate root. So if you have stored your relative path in database as

```
  $path = relative/path/to/file
```

you can use

```
src = "/<?php echo $path?>"
```

Comment: Didn't work, thanks for fast reply anyways. Is it possible that since I worked in windows and tutorial is done on mac that I have something like folder permissions, or something trivial like that stoping thumbnails from showing.

Comment: I hope you have firebug.It will show some error in your console. Check if it shows source does not exist or something similar.

Comment: and BTW, you are storing relative paths right !?. If you are storing absolute paths like 'C:/www/something' it wont work when you go live or when you test in different OS. If you are not storing relative paths, do that, and i think it will solve your problem

Comment: I know, but for a starters, I would like to show them at least locally.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that you are using '../some_path', which means go back one level. But , that is with respect to your php file. So, when you are using the same in html ... it will go back one level from the document root, which I guess is C:/wamp/www/, in your case. You need to address this to solve your error.

Comment: solved it by changing 

return $this->upload_dir.DS.$this->filename; to


return $this->upload_dir."/".$this->filename;

Comment: thanks for your interest in helping me, i appreciate it a lot <3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25997/discussion-between-goran-stosic-and-arundex)